# Create dynamic multi-level menus driven by JSON

Tags: angular, typescript

#### The Problem

I am trying to create a dynamic multi-level main navigation (menu) driven by JSON in Angular.

In AngularJS I would have defined a template and used it recursively to dynamically create extra levels of menus as needed.

In Angular I cannot find a way to create these levels of menus dynamically.

For now I have it hard-coded to allow for two levels, but if more levels need to be added in the future, each level will have to be hard-coded to work.

I am looking for a way to do this dynamically based on the JSON returned for the menu.

#### The JSON

```
menu = [
  {
    title: "Menu Item 1",
        url: "/",
        target: "_blank"
    },
    {
    title: "Menu Item 2",
        active: true,
        navigationItems: [
            {
              title: "Sub-Menu Item 1",
              url: "/"
            },
            {
              title: "Sub-Menu Item 2",
              url: "/",
              navigationItems: [
                  {
                      title: "This Level Not Supported Without Hard-Coding"
                  }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### The Markup

```
<div>
    <ul role="menubar">
        <li *ngFor="let link of menu; let i = index;">

            <a 
              [attr.href]="link.href ? link.href : null"
              [attr.target]="link.target ? link.target : null"
              aria-role="menuitem"
              [attr.ariaExpanded]="link.navigationItems && openElements[i] ? true : null"
              [attr.ariaHasPopup]="link.navigationItems ? true : null"
              (click)="link.navigationItems ? openElements[i] = !openElements[i] : null"
              [class]="openElements[i] ? 'open' : null"
            >
              {{link.title}}
            </a>

            <ul *ngIf="link.navigationItems" role="menu">
                <li *ngFor="let link of link.navigationItems">
                    <a [attr.href]="link.url"
                        [innerHTML]="link.title"
                        [attr.target]="link.target ? link.target : null"
                        role="menuitem"
                    >
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### A Working Example

https://plnkr.co/edit/lpLxHlKtwCJUukoruxq2?p=preview

#### The Solution

I need a way to make sure that any number of levels can be added to this menu based on the structure of the JSON returned from the data service attached to the component without the need for hard-coded levels in the markup for every level.

Comment: I have posted answer to this question quite a long time ago. You can also check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61746097/9590251

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setup a custom recursive component

NavItem.d.ts

```
export interface NavItem {
  title: string;
  active: boolean;
  target: string;
  url: string;
  navigationItems: NavItem[];
}
```

NavItem.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavItem } from 'NavItem.d.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-item',
  template: 'NavItem.component.html'
})
export class NavItemComponent {

    @Input() private navItems: NavItem[];

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

NavItem.component.html

```
<ul role="menubar">
  <li *ngFor="let item of navItems">
    <a ...>{{ item.title }}</a>
    <nav-item *ngIf="item.navigationItems" [navItems]="item.navigationItems"></nav-item>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Usage: Inside an existing template that has access to the navItems

```
<nav-item [navItems]="navItems"></nav-item>
```

Comment: Can you please show an implementation of this creating multiple levels dynamically?

Comment: @StephenRios I'm not really sure what you're asking.  You would use this like any other custom component.  Assuming you've already loaded all the NavItems, you would have a `<nav-item navItems="navItems"></nav-item>` in one of your existing templates.  The nested components will generate themselves.  The only thing I left out in the above is registering with the module.

Comment: That implementation is what I was looking for so that the answer will be complete.  If you will add it to your answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-menu-angular-8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.ts

Comment: @sheucm thanks mate, exactly what i was looking for